# OpenGraph: how can i specify a filter in FB.api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have built a Facebook app using OpenGraph that permits the users to write reviews on concerts, so that I've defined a `concert_id` attribute on which the user can insert a review.

Now I would like to show all the reviews inserted for a certain `concert_id` but cannot find a way. If I do (in JS)

```
FB.api('/me/MY_APP:action', { limit: 0}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

I get all items. This app has to be consumed by mobile, I think it is bad to get all items and, then, filtering only the `concert_id` i need. What do I have to do to apply a `where` condition in OpenGraph to a custom action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Facebook API will not return individual published objects for a particular action, but that's not your only problem. By the look of it, you're trying to bring in ALL the reviews given for a concert, right? (Meaning those by other users too).

The "/me/" part of the Facebook API call will only return those published actions made by the user that is currently logged in. That won't work for you, as you want those of all your users

The only suggestion I can give is to create a simple web service, where you store all the reviews given for the various concerts. Use this service to pull in reviews given for a particular concert. (I use a similar methodology for reviews in an app of my own).

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can tell from the API and the Facebook developer pages, it's not possible to filter a call by custom action property using the public Open Graph API.

Two options I can think of:

Option 1:

Implement the category filter by creating custom category objects:

if "review" is a custom action and

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/me/[name_space]:review
```

returns all review actions then

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/me/[name_space]:review/scifi_movie
GET https://graph.facebook.com/me/[name_space]:review/action_movie
```

return actions specific to movie type, where scifi_movie and action_movie are custom objects. You would need to create one object type for each category.

Option 2:

Implement a custom action for each category, e.g.

```
review_scifi_movie
review_action_movie
```

These are not particularly elegant solutions but perhaps useful as a hack if nothing else works and you really don't want to do filtering on client side.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but how can i handle call to
GET https://graph.facebook.com/me/[name_space]:review/scifi_movie ?

Comment: [name_space] refers to the namespace you specified when you created the app on Facebook. So your call would be FB.api('me/mynamespace:review/scifi_movie', function(response) etc...

Comment: ok, but putting /scifi_movie does not apply a filter. My app permits to insert comments on a concert, based on the concert_id; concert_id is a custom property but if i call graph.facebook.com/me/[ns]:review/XY does not work. As you wrote in your option 2 i could implement a custom action for every item but they are more than 1000, cannot be applied :-(

Comment: Based on your original question I understood that you wanted to filter data by category ("category_id"). If I understand your last comment right you want to retrieve data for individual instances ("concert_id"). My answer is only relevant for category filtering, not for retrieving individual instances.

Object in Open Graph-speak ("link action to object") is equivalent to class, not class instance. So if you have only a few categories you can represent them by objects e.g. rock concert, pop concert, classical concert etc and filter at that level.

Comment: Sorry, i've inserted the question in ambiguous way; i've edited it.

Comment: I believe I've reached the edit limit for my answer, but I just wanted to add that as another option you can store the action id on the client side to avoid expensive calls. When you create an action instance in the Open Graph, it returns the action instance id. Store it with the concert id as a field in your app's db. You can then use these id instead of querying FB.

Answer (score 2):

I dont understand javascript or opengraph..

But when I required in JAVA to fetch reviews made by any user I have used **[FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/)** for that and It retrived me all the **[reviews](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/review/)** and FQL also used to fetch all the tables related to Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can pull that off with the JS SDK.

You can do that in your server though, and since this is a mobile app (or has a mobile version) then that's another good reason to remove this from the client responsibility.

In the server side you can ask facebook for the published actions as you posted, filter them and then return the response.
Another thing that you can do is to save each published action in your db (on each action post you should get an id back from facebook, just persist that) and then you can easily filter the published actions according to what ever criteria you want/need (since you are no longer restricted by the facebook api).

The open graph thing is still pretty new and not tat mature, for example you can't use FQL with it, something that could have been handy for your case.
Regardless though I think that a server solution is best for calculations when mobile is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know exactly  but try this

if (session.authResponse) {

```
    FB.api('/me', {
     fields: 'name, picture' // here mention your fields
    },
    function(response) {
      if (!response.error) {
```

//here response value
});